# dplyr filter() with SQL-like %wildcard%

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data:

```
foo <- data.frame(Company = c("company1", "foo", "test", "food"), Metric = rnorm(4, 10))

> foo
   Company    Metric
1 company1 10.539970
2      foo  9.487823
3     test  9.663994
4     food  9.499327
```

Why does the following code return 0 results (instead of the second and fourth rows)?

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

foo %>% dplyr::filter(Company %like% "%foo%")
```

I'm trying to use the SQL-equivalent wildcard filter on a particular input string to `dplyr::filter`, using the `%like%` operator from the `data.table` package.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you get `%like%` working? Is that a custom defined function or a function from another package?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Plz see my answer below. I changed it to `foo %>% dplyr::filter(Company %like% "foo")` and it works.

Comment: `like` is from `data.table` package

Comment: @DhawalKapil are you sure `%like%` is from the `data.table` package? I don't have `data.table` install on my system and `%like%` still works on a database back-end `tbl(con, "table_name") %>% filter(Company %like% "foo")`.

Comment: yes see page no 57 here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf

Comment: @DhawalKapil those are 2 very different implementations of `like`. In the data table document you cited, `like` is implemented as a "Convenience function for calling grep.", while the [dbplyr reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/dbplyr.pdf) says "All other functions will be preserved as is. R’s infix functions (e.g.%like%) will be converted to their SQL equivalents (e.g.LIKE)."

Answer (score 31):

You can use:

```
filter(foo, grepl("foo", Company, fixed = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
  Company    Metric
1     foo  9.906805
2    food 10.464493
```

As Dhawal Kapil pointed out I think `%like%` is from [data.table](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/like):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(foo)
DT[Company %like% 'foo']
```

Output:

```
   Company    Metric
1:     foo  9.906805
2:    food 10.464493
```

Comment: Sure.  Just making it a little faster

Comment: Thanks for the base answer. Portable

Comment: @Nova No problem. Happy to hear it is useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

You can use with library(stringr)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
foo <- data.frame(Company = c("company1", "foo", "test", "food"), Metric = rnorm(4, 10))

foo %>% filter(str_detect(Company,"foo"))
```

as well as any other Regular expression

```
foo %>% filter(str_detect(Company,"^f"))
```

Comment: Hadleys says that this never worked as expected and is now removed version dbplyr 1.4.0 https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/295

Answer (score 17):

Figured it out; figure I'll leave this up in case it helps somebody else in the future:

```
library(data.table)   # For like function (%like%)
foo <- foo %>% dplyr::filter(Company %like% "foo")
```

Without the `"`s around `foo` in the original question, returns the correct data.frame. Still not sure if you can use the `%` as an anchor in SQL (e.g. `%foo` or `foo%`), but the above works for what I needed it to do.

Comment: No one has a clue where you got `%like%` from, btw

Comment: `grepl()` doesn't get translated to SQL, it can only be used on a data frame. `%like%` is useful when dplyr is used on a database back-end.  Filtering in the database is useful on a large table, which would be too large to load entirely into R. You can see the SQL statement generated by `dplyr` by calling the `explain()` function. `foo %>% filter(Company %like% "foo") %>% explain()`.

Comment: @PaulRougieux  would you know anyway to filter based on letter beginning, e.g. beginning with "f" something like: `dplyr::filter(Company %like% "^f")`. dbplyr no longer supports `str_detect` https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/295

Comment: @user63230 this might depend on which database back-end you have behind dplyr. `Company %like% "f%"` could be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With new updates to stringr 1.5.0
str_like() will make filters like this a breeze.

```
foo |> filter(str_like(Company, "foo%"))
```

this will filter the rows as needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative using dplyr + SQL:**

With sql() escaping from dplyr you can put native SQL (depending on your Data Base flavor) directly in the pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>% filter(sql("Company LIKE ('%foo%')")
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert that variable into same case for all records

```
foo$Company <- toupper(foo$Company)
```

then apply filter

```
foo <- foo[Company %like% 'foo']
```

This will give the subset where Company could be:

```
WESTFOO FIRST NATION-LGS,
SPRINGER EUFOO OIL CO,
US FOO,
CITIFOO NA
```

Comment: did you mean tolower()?