# Pass SQL functions in dplyr filter function on database

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr`'s automatic SQL backend to query subtable from a database table. E.g.

```
my_tbl <- tbl(my_db, "my_table")
```

where `my_table` in the database looks like

```
batch_name    value
batch_A_1     1
batch_A_2     2
batch_A_2     3
batch_B_1     8
batch_B_2     9
...
```

I just want the data from `batch_A_#`, regardless of the number.

If I were writing this in SQL, I could use

```
select * where batch_name like 'batch_A_%'
```

If I were writing this in R, I could use a few ways to get this: `grepl()`, `%in%`, or `str_detect()`

```
# option 1
subtable <- my_tbl %>% select(batch_name, value) %>%
    filter(grepl('batch_A_', batch_name, fixed = T))
# option 2
subtable <- my_tbl %>% select(batch_name, value) %>%
    filter(str_detect(batch_name, 'batch_A_'))
```

All of these give the following Postgres error: `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`

So, how do I pass in SQL string functions or matching functions to help make the generated dplyr SQL query able to use a more flexible range of functions in `filter`?

(FYI the `%in%` function does work, but requires listing out all possible values. This would be okay combined with `paste` to make a list, but does not work in a more general regex case)

Comment: Doesn't `tbl(my_db, sql(select * where batch_name %like% 'batch_A_%'))` work

Comment: @shayaa Sorry for the delay, of course that's right! For more complicated queries, I'm not sure this would always work, but I can't think of a counterexample right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "`dplyr`-only" solution would be this

```r
tbl(my_con, "my_table") %>% 
  filter(batch_name %like% "batch_A_%") %>% 
  collect()
```

Full [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html):

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(dbplyr)
  library(RPostgreSQL)
})

my_con <- 
  dbConnect(
    PostgreSQL(),
    user     = "my_user",
    password = "my_password",
    host     = "my_host",
    dbname   = "my_db"
  )

my_table <- tribble(
  ~batch_name,    ~value,
  "batch_A_1",     1,
  "batch_A_2",     2,
  "batch_A_2",     3,
  "batch_B_1",     8,
  "batch_B_2",     9
)

copy_to(my_con, my_table)

tbl(my_con, "my_table") %>% 
  filter(batch_name %like% "batch_A_%") %>% 
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   batch_name value
#> *      <chr> <dbl>
#> 1  batch_A_1     1
#> 2  batch_A_2     2
#> 3  batch_A_2     3

dbDisconnect(my_con)
#> [1] TRUE
```

This works because any functions that dplyr doesn't know how to
translate will be passed along as is, see
[`?dbplyr::translate\_sql`](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/translate_sql.html).

Hat-tip to [@PaulRougieux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2641825/paul-rougieux) for his recent comment
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831651/2114932)

Answer (score 0):

**Using dplyr**

Get the table batch_name from the database as dataframe and use it for further data analysis.

```
library("dplyr")
my_db <- src_postgres(dbname = "database-name", 
                      host = "localhost", 
                      port = 5432, 
                      user = "username",
                      password = "password")

df <- tbl(my_db, "my_table")
df %>% filter(batch_name == "batch_A_1")
```

**Using DBI and RPostgreSQL**

Get the table by sending sql query

```
library("DBI")
library("RPostgreSQL")  
m <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")    
con <- dbConnect(drv = m,
                 dbname = "database-name", 
                 host = "localhost", 
                 port = 5432,
                 user = "username",
                 password = "password")    
df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE batch_name %LIKE% 'batch_A_%'")

library("dplyr")
df %>% filter(batch_name == "batch_A_1")
```

Comment: Can you edit this to reflect the fact that I wanted to use SQL's regular expression function `like`? Your first code section is incorrect because it uses an explicit batch_name. The second code section is good because it uses an explicit where statement in the query (which I forgot about), however it still uses an explicit batch_name.

Comment: it was missing FROM clause for table_name. You can replace it with the name of one of the tables in your database

Comment: The first code gets the entire table 'my_table'. Then dplyr library command is used on the results from the database query

Comment: The second code queries the table with column 'batch_name' matching the pattern of 'batch_A_'