# How to filter by a string containing variables in dbplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I normally use `filter` with `grepl` in dplyr, but when using `dbplyr`. I get an error that grepl is not a recognized function. My guess is that it can't translate to SQL server. What is a way around this with `dbplyr`

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(dbplyr)
library(nycflights13)

## Working chunk
con <-DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "flights", flights)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT origin, flight 
FROM flights WHERE origin like '%jf%'")
## End working chunk

## The below code does not work 
flights <- tbl(con,"flights")
flights %>% 
  select(origin, flight) %>% 
  filter(grepl('jf', origin))
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL? Wrapping the call in `do` sometimes works.

Comment: MS SQL Server. Can you explain `do` or link to an example?

Comment: Something like `iris %>% do(mutate(., is_setosa = grepl('set', Species)))` It's probably not the best way to do things, though; I'm sure there's a more native solution.

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198795/7416441) effective.

Here is the code that works for your case:

```
dplyr::tbl(con, "flights") %>% 
    filter(origin %like% '%jf%') %>%
    collect()
```

Answer (score 3):

I frequently use `grepl` with a pipe to match multiple values. For `postgresql` If you want to match multiple values `similar to` will also work:

```
dplyr::tbl(con, "flights") %>% 
    filter(origin %similar to% '(JF|LG)%') %>%
    collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not quiet sure what your asking but have u tried any `at` functions?

eg..

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("cyl")), funs("123" = .+1))
```